# Create member object using constructor arguments, or pass reference to object via constructor

Tags: c++

I'm not entirely sure about the proper C++ terminology, so I'll just illustrate what I'm trying to achieve by giving a Java example since it should be pretty obvious:

```
public class LcdDecorator {
    private HD44780Lcd lcd;

    public LcdDecorator(int rows, int cols, int i2cAddress) {
        this.lcd = new HD44780Lcd(rows, cols, i2cAddress);
    }
}
```

or... alternatively...

```
public class LcdDecorator {
    private HD44780Lcd lcd;

    public LcdDecorator(HD44780Lcd lcd) {
        this.lcd = lcd;
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, there's no real concern about scope... LcdDecorator is a Singleton that gets created in setup(), then lives forever and gets used by loop() until the power gets shut off.

##### Here's what I've attempted so far:

`LcdFacade.h`:

```
#ifndef CORECONTROLLER_LCDFACADE_H
#define CORECONTROLLER_LCDACADE_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include "../.pio/libdeps/megaatmega2560/HD44780_LCD_PCF8574/src/HD44780_LCD_PCF8574.h"

class LcdFacade {

public:
    LcdFacade(uint8_t rows, uint8_t cols, uint8_t i2cAddress) ;
};

#endif //CORECONTROLLER_LCDFACADE_H
```

`LcdFacade.cpp`:

```
#include "LcdFacade.h"
#include "../.pio/libdeps/megaatmega2560/HD44780_LCD_PCF8574/src/HD44780_LCD_PCF8574.h"

HD44780LCD lcd;

LcdFacade::LcdFacade (uint8_t rows, uint8_t cols, uint8_t i2cAddress) : lcd{rows, cols, i2cAddress} {
    // ... the rest of the constructor goes here ...
}
```

note: I also tried using parentheses instead of braces for lcd's constructor:

```
LcdFacade::LcdFacade(uint8_t rows, uint8_t cols, uint8_t i2cAddress) : lcd(rows, cols, i2cAddress) {
```

In CLion, the 'lcd{rows, cols, i2caddress}' portion of the constructor in LcdFacade.cpp is red-underlined, and reports `member initializer 'lcd' does not name a non-static data member or base class`

Meanwhile, gcc(?) reports `error: no matching function for call to 'HD44780LCD::HD44780LCD()` on line 4 of LcdFacade.cpp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define

```cpp
HD44780LCD lcd;
```

at global scope, you are creating a global variable that is initialized
before `main()` is called. In this case, it is initialized with the
default constructor `HD44780LCD::HD44780LCD()`, which does not exist,
hence the error. You could avoid this error by calling a suitable
constructor in the initialization, e.g.

```cpp
HD44780LCD lcd(4, 20, 0x23);
```

but this may be inconvenient to you.

If you want to initialize `lcd` in the constructor of `LcdFacade`, then
it must be a non-static member of the class:

```cpp
// In LcdFacade.h:
class LcdFacade {
public:
    LcdFacade(uint8_t rows, uint8_t cols, uint8_t i2cAddress);
private:
    HD44780LCD lcd;  // <- non-static member
};

// In LcdFacade.cpp:
LcdFacade::LcdFacade(uint8_t rows, uint8_t cols, uint8_t i2cAddress)
: lcd(rows, cols, i2cAddress) {
    ...
}
```